# Google AdManager viewability measurement on Android and Compose does not work properly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ads, google-ad-manager

We have the problem with our AdManger viewability measurement that it is only tracked after scrolled out of view and back again.

We brought everything back to a simple ad UI and it still does not work as expected. Does anybody see something wrong in the code?

That’s the code we are using:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun AdTestScreen(viewModel: AdTestViewModel = getViewModel()) {
        val adItems by viewModel.adItems.collectAsState(initial = emptyList()) // our ad information comes from the backend
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val webViews = rememberSaveable(adItems) { adItems.map { generateAdManagerAdView(context, it) } }
    
        LazyColumn() {
            items(webViews) { adView ->
                Text(text = "Some Lorem Ipsum text..."
                AndroidView(
                    factory = {
                        adView.removeFromParent()
                        adView
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun generateAdManagerAdView(context: Context, ad: Ad) =
        AdManagerAdView(context).apply {
            adUnitId = ad.adUnitId
            setAdSizes(ad.adSizes)
            doOnLayout {
                loadAd(AdManagerAdRequest.Builder().apply {
                    // some custom targeting is done
                }.build())
            }
        }
```

We are using the following versions:

```kotlin
    const val ads = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0"
    const val auth = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0"
    const val adsIdentifier = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1"
    
    const val kotlinVersion = "1.7.10"
    const val composeVersion = "1.2.1"
    const val composeCompilerVersion = "1.3.0"
```

**Expected behaviour:**

When the ad is displayed the measuring should start. For me this is defined as seeing many `GMA Debug CONTENT .... "uri":"https://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?...` requests in the logcat (after you enabled Google Ads Debug Mode https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/13685676/enable-debug-logging-for-ads?hl=en). As long as the ad is displayed, the measurement calls are sent until a maximum is reached.

**Current behaviour:**

When the ad is displayed nothing is measured. Even when you scroll up and down (the Ad is always in a visible area), nothing is tracked.
BUT: when the ad gets out of visible area and you go back, it starts measuring.

Comment: I had a not same but similar problem and found a workaround, wrote down here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76100292/ad-impressions-are-not-count-when-admanageradview-is-used-with-jetpack-compose/76100293#76100293

Comment: Thanks @OyaCanli ! Your workaround has fixed our issue as well! I will link you and your answer in an answer or feel free to write it by your own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@OyaCanli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758208/oya-canli), I found a solution/workaround for this problem: [Ad impressions are not count when AdManagerAdView is used with Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76100292/ad-impressions-are-not-count-when-admanageradview-is-used-with-jetpack-compose/76100293#76100293) :

> I found this workaround proposed in Kotlin slack for NativeAdView in Jetpack Compose, https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1664105063510709, and I improved it a bit. Calling adView.rootView.requestLayout() from onAdLoaded solved the issue and I see now onAdImpression is called right after onAdLoaded.

```kotlin
AdManagerAdView(context).apply {
    adUnitId = ad.id
    setAdSizes(*ad.sizes)
    appEventListener = createAppEventListener()
    adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded()
            rootView.requestLayout()
        }
    }
    loadAd(bannerAdModule.adRequest(ad))
}
```